# disply cube in saiku through pentaho schema workbench

Tags: mysql, xsd, pentaho, workbench, saiku

I am trying to publish cube which is created on pentaho schema workbench and trying to analyses the result into bi server, in this procedure i am successfully published the cube but facing exception of **Table not found in statement exception** in saiku server even if the table is exist in the mysql database so what can i do to resolve this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Check your data sources file - Saiku is probably not using the right schema for the database so is looking in a different place.

Comment: No Actually everything is proper it was working before but i don't know what is going wrong now it is giving me an error, if you can tell that what are the places where i have to define connection apart from pentaho schema workbench?

Comment: Got the solution, the problem was of JNDI Connection.